How do I make a loop-de-loop without distorting the track?
I'm relatively new to Blender and I'm trying to make a race track. There is supposed to be a loop-de-loop and I'm using the array-curve modifier technique to do that. However, when I try this, the track tilts at the end of the loop, and that's a result that I don't want. Is there a way to make a loop-de-loop that doesn't cause the track to distort? Thank you for reading


You should be able to fix the problem by tweaking the Tilt value of the control point, open the N panel > Item > Tilt, or CtrlT:



Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
The result above isn't exactly right, because I was too lazy to figure bezier handles, as auto handles didn't give me correct result. But the principle - consistent curve normal - is there. Of course you don't necessarily want a shape like this for an actual loop de loop, especially if it's a road rather than rails and you want to help the vehicle to stay on the right path. Then some normal twisting would actually be desired.
The way I achieved it is by creating a circle, edit, set handles to free, remove cyclic, duplicate one of the ends, connect it with the other end, extrude it, then ✲ CtrlNumpad +, H to hide 2 last points, select the other end, extrude in the opposite direction. Since I was working in 2D (XY axes), I could then just set the twist method to Z-up:

Imgur mirror
Then I moved the 3rd, 4th and 5th, 6th and 7th points up by 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 and 0.4 respectively, and set the 3rd, 4th and 5th point handles to auto (this is imperfect).
For bevel I just used a line parallel to y axis.
At the end I rotated the object 90° around y axis and moved it up by 1 unit (the default radius of the circle).
Here's a geonodes equivalent:

Imgur mirror
It's better because the circle part correctly linearly changes its z component (before rotation; its resulting x component), but the (resulting) horizontal paths are parallel to y axis and never ease into the loop. You can fix it by applying subdivision surface just after merging by distance (effect will depend on resolution of curves) or doing something custom (calculating a circumference of the circle and dividing by spiral height to get the ratio of change).

Imgur mirror
